# Detect if python pip subpackage is installed by name

Tags: pip

Airflow module comes with a main pip package `apache-airflow` and multiple subpackages to install only what we need (check doc https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#extra-packages)

I would like to test if a subpackage is installed or not (and for example get a bash command to know if `apache-airflow[mysql]` is installed).

To know if `apache-airflow` is installed, I can do `pip show apache-airflow` and get `0` as exit code if installed, `1` otherwise. If I do `pip show apache-airflow['mysql']`, I always get `1` as exit code, the subpackage being installed or not.

And I could not find any option for that. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "subpackage" you're referring to here is called a "setuptools extra".  pip does not record these anywhere in the filesystem.  You can however detect whether they are installed by iterating the installation metadata and testing whether each dependent package is installed.

Fortunately, there's a method in `pkg_resources` which [does this for you](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-workingset-methods)

I tested with `jsonschema[format]` as it was easy for me to install / uninstall.

### with `jsonschema[format]` installed

```
$ python -c 'import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require("jsonschema[format]")'
$ echo $?
0
```

### without the dependencies of the `[format]` extra

```
$ python -c 'import pkg_resources; pkg_resources.require("jsonschema[format]")'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 967, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 853, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'webcolors; extra == "format"' distribution was not found and is required by jsonschema

$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Is there any way to access this extras inside setup.py? I wan't to include different packages based on the provided extra.

Comment: @Jack a bit unrelated to this question but that's `extras_require`